# Setting up a JavaScript that writes whether the store is Open or Closed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to setup a basic JavaScript, where if the day is Sunday or Saturday, it will write "Closed" in the HTML, or if it's later than 5:30pm, or it's earlier than 9:00am, it will also write out closed.

My main problem is that the if statement always seems to return true. I've tried multiple things to fix this and to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Code: http://pastebin.com/R5kE6fX6

Comment: Dont put the statement in "". if(true) instead of if(" true")

Comment: Please include the code in your question, rather than relying on an external site

Comment: The js time is based on computer time wich is unreliable (some people dont care about their computers clock) so use server clock + serverside script (php) instead

Comment: @Jonasw this is being uploaded to github, can't use php sadly. Also taking the statement out of "" causes the script to not work for some reason.

Comment: @pepuso: However,  does my first comment work?

Comment: It sadly does not. @Jonasw

Comment: Your code isnt working in any case, cause youve made logical mistakes. Try to debug it on your own

Comment: If I was able to debug it on my own I wouldn't be coming to a forum to ask for help @Jonasw

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294774/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, its more an advanced comment on  code styling.

Your if statements look complicated, i still dont understand them. To improve your code make it more readable. That makes it easier for you and us to improve it.
For example:

```
status="opened";

if(date=="wednesday"){
    if(time>closetime){
        status="closed. Its too late";
    }
    if(time<opentime){
        status="closed. youre to early";
    }
} else {
    //code for other dates
}

//echo code
document.write(status);
```

Comment: Understood, apologies have less than 5 weeks worth of coding experience with and very new to this forum. Again though, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Pepuso: No worries. There are just so many "could u do this for me" in this forum, so im a bit agressive right now. Im still learning to, so i understand your point of view, but i learn trough reading docs and figuring it out myself. I think stackoverflow should focus on advanced problems, that are not solvable with docs + debugging

Comment: Should've probably stated that I didn't really want the answer done for me just some hints to get me moving :p Regardless, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @pepuso: thats good. I give an upvote to the others, because i think its fair

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code :

```
// Place back slashes in front of any grammar, used for checking open or closed based on day and time.
var dayornight = new Date();
var opened = 9;
var closed = [23, 59];
var closedThurs = 19;
var closedWed = 16;
var day = dayornight.getDay();

alert(day);

if(day == 0 || day == 6 || dayornight.getHours() < opened) { 
  if( day == 4 && dayornight.getHours() >= closedThurs || day == 3 && dayornight.getHours() >= closedWed) {
    if(dayornight.getHours() >= closed[0] && dayornight.getMinutes() >= closed[1]){

      document.write("<span class=\"Closed\">Closed</span>");
      alert("Closed is working");

    }
  }
} else {
  document.write("<span class=\"Open\">Open</span>");
  alert("Opened else is working");
}
```

Comment: It now returns false, However, it doesn't seem to return true.

Comment: @Pepuso Which means you logic is possibly wrong. Please do your homework.

Comment: Theres still a logical mistake: if the first if is true but the second isnt, it returns nothing

Comment: @Jonasw I can see the problem, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing if a string has some content:

```
if("day == 0 || day == 6 || dayornight.getHours() < opened") {}
```

In this example the whole condition is a string (encapsulated by `"`). And `if("some string")` will return `true` as long as the string has at least one character in it.

You need to use conditions as JS code – which means to remove all those superfluous quotes.

This should work:

```
if( day == 0 || day == 6 || dayornight.getHours() < opened) {}
```

By the way: Please start using a code editor with syntax highlighting, while developing. As you can see in the two snippets above, a string is completely in one color, whereas different parts of the code may get different colors in an editor with syntax highlighting. This is super-helpful when facing such mistakes.

Comment: This does make it so it returns false. But, it won't return true now. @JonasW did point out that their was logical errors in it, if you can help me find some I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @Pepuso Please do your homework yourself. Start learning how to debug code and have fun finding those bugs. This is, what a programmer does…

Comment: I do try to. Sometimes I cannot find the right answer that I'm looking for. I will take these into account though. Thank you.

Comment: @Pepuso Start using `console.log()` a lot and at every possible place. Print each variable to the console and see if their values are what you expect. Next delete any conditions (store them somewhere else for the moment, e.g. an empty text file) and start over with most simple condition you can think of. Only of the most simple condition is working, start re-adding more code to it.

Comment: Will start trying to make that a habit. I am beginning to see how easily I could've found the logical problem myself. Again though, I am listening and taking into account what I am being told, and will start using the advice I'm given.